# Why these source codes (C++) are provided different result for Chemical Reaction?

Tags: c++, c++14

When I run these source code on Linux, Windows and online compiler it always provide different result, but I think both source code are same. Please describe any idea about these codes.

First Code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double a=100.0,b=50.0,c=0.0,da,db,dc;
    double k1=0.008,k2=0.002,delta=0.1,T=5.0,t,time=0.0;
    int N;
    t=(T/delta);
    N=(int)t;
    cout<<"Time"<<"\t"<<"A"<<"\t"<<"B"<<"\t"<<"C"<<"\t\n";
    cout<<time<<"\t"<<a<<"\t"<<b<<"\t"<<c<<"\t\n";
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        //Look the below line
        a=a+(k2*c-k1*a*b)*delta;
        b=b+(k2*c-k1*a*b)*delta;
        c=c+(2*(k1*a*b-k2*c))*delta;

        time+=delta;
        cout<<time<<"\t"<<a<<"\t"<<b<<"\t"<<c<<"\t\n";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Second Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double a=100.0,b=50.0,c=0.0,da,db,dc;
    double k1=0.008,k2=0.002,delta=0.1,T=5.0,t,time=0.0;
    int N;
    t=(T/delta);
    N=(int)t;
    cout<<"Time"<<"\t"<<"A"<<"\t"<<"B"<<"\t"<<"C"<<"\t\n";
    cout<<time<<"\t"<<a<<"\t"<<b<<"\t"<<c<<"\t\n";
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        //Separate the previous code into two line.
        da=k2*c-k1*a*b;
        db=k2*c-k1*a*b;
        dc=2*(k1*a*b-k2*c);

        a=a+da*delta;
        b=b+db*delta;
        c=c+dc*delta;

        time+=delta;
        cout<<time<<"\t"<<a<<"\t"<<b<<"\t"<<c<<"\t\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output :
After first iteration:**

```
first code gives  : 0.1 96  46.16   7.09018 
second code gives : 0.1 96  46      8
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that in the first listing, the value of a has changed by the time you are giving a new value to b.

```
a=a+(k2*c-k1*a*b)*delta; //a is now different
b=b+(k2*c-k1*a*b)*delta;
             ^ now different
```

In the second listing, da, db, and dc compute based on an unchanging value of a, b and c.

```
da=k2*c-k1*a*b; 
db=k2*c-k1*a*b;
           ^ ^ Still the same.
```

Comment: Oh, yes thanks a lot.

Comment: @AshrafulHaque Things like this are often easier to spot when variables have descriptive names. Don't be like the person who wrote this code. Adopt and follow an intelligible naming scheme.